# VIM-version with support for system clipboard (in terminal)

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I am running KDE Neon (Ubuntu) and want to be able to yank and copy to/from system clipboard. The standard vim application that is preinstalled on Ubuntu systems does not support this.

What version of VIM should I run to get this support? I want to run VIM in the terminal, so gvim is not an option.
I have been looking at nvim, but it grabs .vim and .vimrc from somwhere else???

Comment: How did you determine that the Ubuntu vim doesn't support it?

Comment: ``vim --version`` shows -clipboard and -xterm_clipboard

Comment: ubuntu, by default, installs vim-tiny. Do a `apt-get install vim` and try again. Let us know if it does not fix the issue

Comment: I still have the same version of vim, missing clipard and xterm_clipboard @dlmeetei

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$ sudo apt-get install vim-gtk` will give you a Vim built against X with the `+clipboard` feature.

Comment: I want to run vim in the terminal, not as a standalone window. I said in the question that gvim is not an option because of that.

Comment: Ooh nevermind, this added ``+clipboard`` and ``+xterm_clipboard`` to ``vim --version`` without having to run gvim :) Thanks.

Comment: Perfect!! After installing vim-gtk I create a maping in my `.vimrc` like this `vnoremap <F5> "+y` so now when ever I am in visual mode and I press F5 it's yank all the selected text to the system clipboard. Thanks romainl

Comment: @ThormaWeb.com, take a look at `:help 'clipboard'` for an even better method.

Answer (score 0):

Consider switch to [neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim).

See also https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/30787/install-vim-with-clipboard-support-but-without-gvim